# Библиотека для записи видео с камеры

Tags: java, библиотеки

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите библиотеку `java` для записи видео с камеры. Желательно с хорошим мануалом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, OpenCV. Есть биндинги к [Java](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html). На разных платформах использует различные способы - на Win - это dshow или vfw, на macx - QuickTime.

Comment: а можете привести пример кода для работы с камерой?

Comment: [здесь](http://robocraft.ru/blog/computervision/275.html). Там правда плюсы, но просто подбираете аналогичные методы с java.